# Checkbox should be checked if the value is passed by javascript in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

i have check box

```
<input type="checkbox" id="total_distance" {!! (if(value=="1")) ? 'checked="true"': '' !!}>
```

in javascript i am passing value to checkbox `id="total_distance"`

```
var a = 1;
document.getElementById('total_distance').value = a;
```

i want if passing `value == 1` use this value in it and compare it `{!! (**here compare**) ? 'checked="true"': '' !!}`

Comment: if any answer helped you please mark it as the best answer. so others can use it too
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this one. this should solve your problem with setting value in javascript as you wrote

```
<input type="checkbox" id="total_distance" {{this.value == 1 ? 'checked' : ''}}>
```